# Angular 2 Animating the void state of a routed component

Tags: angular

I'm using the host property of the component decorator to declare an animation trigger, which includes a transition state for * => void.

I know it's triggering because I've applied a duration of 800ms (for testing, I changed it to 5 seconds to be sure), and when I click a routerLink which takes it to a different component, there is a 5 second delay occurring.

The problem is, is that there's no animation taking place.  It should be sliding to the left and fading to opacity: 0.

Here's the code within the component decorator:

```
host: {
   '[@slideInOutright]': 'true',
},
animations: [ 

   trigger('slideInOutright', [

    state('*', style({transform: 'translateX(0)'})),

    transition('void => *', [
      style({transform: 'translateX(150px)', opacity:'1'}),
      animate('300ms 500ms ease-out')
    ]),
    transition('* => void', [
      animate('800ms', style({transform: 'translateX(-60px)',opacity: '0'}))
    ])
  ])

 ]
```

Answer (score 0):

You should call your state `true` instead of `*`.

Comment: Still no luck; same behavior.

Comment: Oh, I think I know the issue... the details.component.html is wrapped in a div that has an *ngIf= on it.  I guess there's an issue where it'll ignore animating anything included.

If I add anything outside of that if, the animation takes place.  Ugh.